# Can anyone help me restructure the following code so that it avoids shared mutability?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a requirement where I want to fetch data from the database by passing a list of keys (in this case numbers) and the database has a limitation of accepting a certain number of parameters (say 500). The code I have written is as follows;

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
List < Cat > catList = new ArrayList < > ();
List < Dog > dogList = new ArrayList < > ();
List < Integer > numbers = Stream.iterate(1, e - > e + 1)
    .limit(5000)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
Collection < List < Integer >> partitionedListOfNumbers = numbers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(num - > counter.getAndIncrement() / 500))
    .values(); //Split the list into lists of size 500
partitionedListOfNumbers.stream()
    .forEach(list - > {
        List < Cat > interimCatList = catRepo.fetchCats(list); //Cat list to be fetched from the database
        catList.addAll(interimCatList);
        List < Dog > interimDogList = dogRepo.fetchDogs(list); //Dog list to be fetched from database
        dogList.addAll(interimDogList);
    });
```

I know the above function isn't pure as it is mutating the catList and the dogList. Would you mind to help me restructure the code so that it avoids shared mutability?

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
List < Cat > catList = new ArrayList < > ();
List < Dog > dogList = new ArrayList < > ();
List < Integer > numbers = Stream.iterate(1, e - > e + 1)
    .limit(5000)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
Collection < List < Integer >> partitionedListOfNumbers = numbers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(num - > counter.getAndIncrement() / 500))
    .values(); //Split the list into lists of size 500
partitionedListOfNumbers.stream()
    .forEach(list - > {
        List < Cat > interimCatList = catRepo.fetchCats(list); //Cat list to be fetched from the database
        catList.addAll(interimCatList);
        List < Dog > interimDogList = dogRepo.fetchDogs(list); //Dog list to be fetched from database
        dogList.addAll(interimDogList);
    });
```

Comment: Just use two separate streams (one for `Cat`, one for `Dog`), and then `Stream#collect`. Note if `#fetch*` is blocking, then you're going to be waiting a while for each list retrieval. You can also take advantage of `#flatMap` to turn the `Stream<List<Animal>>` you receive into a `Stream<Animal>`. My primary advice, however, is to write this first without streams, and get a feel for what you're trying to accomplish. It appears that you've got a lot of stream work that isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection<List<Integer>> partitionedListOfNumbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,5000)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(num - > counter.getAndIncrement() / 500))
    .values();
List<Cat> catList = partitionedListOfNumbers.stream()
    .map(list -> catRepo.fetchCats(list))
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Dog> dogList = partitionedListOfNumbers.stream()
    .map(list -> dogRepo.fetchDogs(list))
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could extract the logic to retrieve animals based on list of lists to a method that accepts a function to avoid the slight duplication of the code, but I think it solves your problem?

Comment: `IntStream` doesn’t support `Collector`; you need `.boxed()` before `collect`. Further, you are still using `counter` whereas the OP wants to change exactly that (“*so that it avoids shared mutability*”). Why not just use the `num` parameter, i.e. `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(num -> (num - 1)/ 500))`? There is, by the way, no guaranty that the lists are in the right order after the `groupingBy`, in contrast to the cheaper `List<List<Integer>> partitionedListOfNumbers = IntStream.range(0, 10).map(i -> i * 500 + 1) .mapToObj(num -> IntStream.range(num, num + 500).boxed().toList()) .toList();`